# WM_KEYDOWN arrives, WM_CHAR is skipped

Tags: c, winapi

I'm trying to replicate the behavior of some hex editor, that handles WM_KEYDOWN and WM_CHAR separately, and they both arrive, in the according order. There it looks like this:

```
case WM_CHAR:
    if(GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) & 0x8000)return 0;
    c[0] = (char)(wParam&0xFF);
    c[1] = 0;
    InputData(c);
    return 0;

case WM_KEYDOWN:
    if(GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) & 0x8000){
        switch(wParam){
        case 0x43: //Ctrl+C
            MemViewCallB(hMemView,WM_COMMAND,MENU_MV_EDIT_COPY,0);
            return 0;
        case 0x56: //Ctrl+V
            MemViewCallB(hMemView,WM_COMMAND,MENU_MV_EDIT_PASTE,0);
            return 0;
        case 0x5a: //Ctrl+Z
            UndoLastPatch(); break;
        case 0x41: //Ctrl+A
            // Fall through to Ctrl+G
        case 0x47: //Ctrl+G
            GotoAddress(hwnd); break;
        case 0x46: //Ctrl+F
            OpenFindDialog(); break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
```

My code is this:

```
case WM_CHAR: {
    if (GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) & 0x8000) return 0;
    char c[2], result = -1;
    c[0] = (char) wParam & 0xFF;
    c[1] = 0;
    if (MouseArea == TEXT) {
        //parse as a character
    } else {
        //parse as a number
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

case WM_KEYDOWN:
    if (GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) & 0x8000) {
        switch(wParam) {
        case 0x43: // Ctrl+C
            HexEditorProc(HexEditorHWnd, WM_COMMAND, IDC_C_HEX_COPY_AUTO, 0);
            return 0;
        case 0x47: // Ctrl+G
            HexEditorProc(HexEditorHWnd, WM_COMMAND, IDC_C_HEX_GOTO, 0);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
```

And only WM_KEYDOWN arrives.

Sure, I tried to do it all inside WM_KEYDOWN, by handling all the presses outside `(GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) & 0x8000)` as chars, converting them to unicode using `ToUnicode()`, but I got variables passed to it corrupted at the end of Proc. For some reason, there's no deep tutorial on how to use it `ToUnicode()`. So I tried going with 2 different messages and one of them skips another...

The message loop looks like this:

```
while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE))
{
    if (HexEditorHWnd && IsDialogMessage(HexEditorHWnd, &msg))
            // stuff?  
        continue;
    if (RamWatchHWnd && IsDialogMessage(RamWatchHWnd, &msg))
    {
        if(msg.message == WM_KEYDOWN) // send keydown messages to the dialog (for accelerators, and also needed for the Alt key to work)
            SendMessage(RamWatchHWnd, msg.message, msg.wParam, msg.lParam);
        continue;
    }
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

What should I add before HexEditor lets continue?

Comment: Calling ToUnicode() is the job of TranslateMessage().  Which appears to be missing from your message loop if you don't get WM_CHAR.  I can't see it from here.

Comment: Polling for messages without removing them from the queue isn't going to end well. Your `PeekMessage`-call should really remove the message, since it is handling it (or trying to anyway). Also note the documentation for [`WM_CHAR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646276.aspx): *"Posted to the window with the keyboard focus when a `WM_KEYDOWN` message is translated by the `TranslateMessage` function."* If you want `WM_CHAR` messages, don't skip the call to `TranslateMessage` (like you're doing).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This little addition seems to fix my problem.

```
if (HexEditorHWnd && IsDialogMessage(HexEditorHWnd, &msg))
{
    if(msg.message == WM_CHAR)
        SendMessage(HexEditorHWnd, msg.message, msg.wParam, msg.lParam);
    continue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're probably not calling `TranslateMessage` in your message loop.

```
while (GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0) > 0)
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg); // here
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

`TranslateMessage` is responsible for, amongst other things, generating `WM_CHAR` messages from `WM_KEYDOWN`.

Comment: I am calling it, but it just skips to `continue`. Added it to the question.

Comment: Your message loop doesn't skip to `continue`, the `continue` skips the call to `TranslateMessage` and `DispatchMessage`.